# LinkedIntList(java)

Tags: java

"RemoveAll" class is a part of Linked List class. The class I wrote, removes all the keys    from a Linked List but it doesn't remove duplicate keys.

Does anybody know why? How I can remove duplicate keys too?

```
public class LinkedIntList {

    private ListNode front; 
    private String name = "front"; 

    // Constructs an empty list.
    public LinkedIntList() {
        front = null;
    }


   public void removeAll(int key){

    if(front == null){ 

         throw new RuntimeException();

       }else if( front.data == (key)) {

      front = front.next;

      return;
   }

     ListNode cur  = front;

     ListNode prev = null;

   while(cur != null  && cur.data != (key) ){

      prev = cur;

      cur = cur.next;
   }

   if(cur == null) 

    throw new RuntimeException();

   
   prev.next = cur.next;

}
```

Comment: I don't see "removeAll" in your code...

Answer (score 1):

If you have duplicates, a brute force approach is to keep calling removeAll() until it returns false.

```
while (myCollection.removeAll(someOthercollection))
   ;  // comment here that the loop does nothing for clarity
```

ADDED: as @Dukeling correctly points out, you shouldn't have to do this.  But if the removeALl() is poorly implemented you may have to.

Comment: `removeAll` is supposed to remove all matching elements and is supposed to only be called once. The name says it all - remove **All**.

Comment: Good point, correct, but I've seen poor implementations where it doesn't.  This is definitely a workaround.

Comment: I just checked the JavaDocs and you are correct.  "Removes _all_ of this collection's elements that are also contained in the specified collection"  Which I didn't know before...

Answer (score 1):

Well, your method only finds the *first* matching key, then attempts to remove that item from the list, then returns.  Once you find the first match, you're going to have to loop, removing items until you find a key that does *not* match (or you hit the end of the list).

Answer (score 1):

```
public void removeAll(T value) {
    if (this.front == null) {
        return;
    }

    Node<T> prevNode = null;
    Node<T> currNode = this.front;

    // If the node we want to remove is front node...
    while (currNode.data.equals(value)) {
        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = currNode.next;
        prevNode.next = null;
    }
    this.front = currNode;

    while (currNode != null) {
        if (currNode.data.equals(value)) {
            prevNode.next = currNode.next;
            currNode.next = null;
        } else {
            prevNode = currNode;
        }
        currNode = prevNode.next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, this question was posted long time ago. Hopefully you have found your answer. But I still posted my solution here :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove nodes while data == key, so that you make sure to remove *all* occurrences, not just the first one.

In the lines `else if( front.data == (key)) { front = front.next;` you are only removing the first occurence. It should be `while ( front.data == (key)) { front = front.next;`

Here again you are only removing one node:
`prev.next = cur.next`
You need a `while cur.data == key` block to adjust the `prev` and `cur` nodes to the *last* occurence of the matching key before calling `prev.next = cur.next;`. Otherwise you'll be only deleting the first occurrence.